# "National Forward published"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'd like to know the meaning of "National Forward published". I have seen it in codes and regulation context, such as those found by [this search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB828GB828&ei=gctFXJH-HY-Q1fAP_5mnkAM&q=%22national%20forward%20published%22&oq=%22national%20forward%20published%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11303.74907..77339...0.0..0.170.2106.0j13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.HPhXrFx8zPM), and couldn't understand it.

Comment: I would assume that the "National Forward" is some sort of publication.  I tried Googling it but there are confusing results from several nations.  You need to give us more context.

Comment: I've nominated this for reopening. I edited the question some time ago in a bid to keep it open. It clearly isn't too ambiguous to be answered as I've answered it. :) I would appreciate some guidance on what other changes people think would be required to re-open.

Comment: @Spagirl: The question is once again open. Evidently your comment above was a very effective way to encourage reopen votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly you won't be able to open the sites in this search for '[BSI "National Foreword](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB828GB828&ei=t89FXN39GOmM1fAPweu2gAo&q=bsi%20%22national%20foreword%22&oq=bsi%20%22national%20foreword%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7614.9676..11164...0.0..0.397.3130.3-9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.h0EqfDeGGnU)"'(note spelling) unless you have a login for the sites, but the search itself is helpful. If you compare it to the results for '["National Forward Published"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB828GB828&ei=gctFXJH-HY-Q1fAP_5mnkAM&q=%22national%20forward%20published%22&oq=%22national%20forward%20published%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11303.74907..77339...0.0..0.170.2106.0j13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.HPhXrFx8zPM)' you will see that the search for 'National Forward Published' only takes us to handful of examples of what appears to be the same document set (I'm hampered by a firewall here at the moment) listing British Standard Institute and European Standard construction industry documents, whereas the BSI search takes us to a multitude of informative sources.

I think what has happened is that someone has prepared a list which intends to show when *National Forewords* for various documents were published, as opposed to *European Forewords*, and got confused between the near homophone pair forward/foreword.

Note that the [BSI Pocket Guide to Standards Development](https://www.bsigroup.com/Documents/about-bsi/NSB/BSI-pocket-guide-to-standards-development-UK-EN.pdf) answers the question:

> What is the development process for European and International Standards?

with

> Following successful formal approval the Standard may be
>   implemented as a British Standard, at which point any conflicting
>   national Standards are withdrawn. This is a requirement for
>   European Standards and optional for International Standards. Any
>   information that the committee believes will support the use of
>   an adopted Standard in the UK may be published in the National
>   Foreword or as a National Annex.